# Translation of 見れば

Tags: translation

I often found sentences with 見れば, and of course the translation will depend on the context of the sentence itself.

I learned that ば is a conditional particle, and I personally sensed that 見れば is often being used as a conclusive statement.

One of the meaning of 見る is to judge, so I thought of 見れば can be translated to "Judging from..." in a conclusive statement.

For example:

言ってみれば

Romanjidesu.com gave examples as follow: in a manner of speaking; as it were; so to speak; if you like; per se

I think it can also be translated as: "Judging from what you said".

Please kindly correct me if I was wrong, thank you.

Comment: Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2717/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19038/9831

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The みれば in 言ってみれば is a subsidiary verb (補助動詞), adding the meaning of "try ~~ing".

言ってみれば is the conditional form of 言ってみる.

言ってみる consists of the te-form of 言う + subsidiary verb みる, meaning "try saying".

So 言ってみれば literally means "If I/you try saying..." → "If I may say so", "So to speak".

Answer (score 1):

I think you often hear that as part of a `~てみれば` construct, which would be the conditional form of `~てみる`.
In this case, the `~てみれば` part alters the verb to mean `If one tried to ~`.

Some phrases are rather common and feel like fixed expressions, such as [`考えてみれば`](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%80%83%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0) (if you think about it), which explains you can come across them quite often.
An example stolen from [ejje.weblio.jp](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%80%83%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0) since I have no imagination:

> 考えてみれば，まだ何も食べていなかった
>
> Come to think of it, I haven't eaten anything yet.

As for `言ってみれば`, [weblio also references it](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A8%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0), with the meaning of "put differently, in other words, that is to say" etc.
I think you can think of it as `if one tried to express it`.

As a side note, I'm note sure whether `見る` is at the origin of the `~てみる` construct, but regardless it's never written in kanji.